# Regex with overlapping and repeating

Tags: c++, regex

Suppose that I have a string `s = "ACBCAACBCBCAB"`.  I would like to find a regex that can give me ALL strings of length 3 that are repeated at least 2 times in `s` (possibly overlapping).  For example, the string `s` gives:

`ACB` (2 times)

`CBC` (3 times)

`BCA` (2 times)

I'm thinking to use `regex = "(?=([ABC]{3}))\1{1,}"`, but it's not quite right.  I'm using C++.

Thank you.

PS: The `s` in the question is an example.  I would like a regex that works for a general `s` (substrings, length 3, are still repeated at least 2 times).  Another example is when `s = "ABABA"`, the substrings are `"ABA"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you matched the regex

```
(?=(.{3}))(?=.+\1)
```

to the string

```
ZABABABCACACABAABADEFGDEF
```

there would be 7 matches (of empty strings) where the contents of capture group 1 for each match are the 3-letter strings shown below.

```
ZABABABCACACABAABADEFGDEF
0123456789012345678901234
 ABA
  BAB
   ABA
       CAC
        ACA
            ABA
                  DEF
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pxh82O/3)

Each of these three-character strings are followed by the same 3-characters appearing at least once in the remainder of the string. As a result, some matches are repeated. We therefore must extract the unique values of the array

```
["ABA", "BAB", "ABA", "CAC", "ACA", "ABA", "DEF"]
```

to obtain

```
["ABA", "BAB", "CAC", "ACA", "DEF"]
```

as the 3-character strings that appear at least twice in the string.

The first match of `(?=(.{3}))` occurs when the regex engine's internal pointer is immediately before `Z`, and capture group 1 contains `ZAB`. We now look for a match of the content of capture group 1 later in the string, beginning right *after* the `Z`. For that reason we need `.+`, rather than `.*` in `(?=.+\1)`. There is no match of `(?=.+\1)`, so the match fails. As lookarounds consume no characters the regex engine's internal pointer has not moved.

The internal pointer is then moved forward one character, to a location immediately before the first `A`, and the content of capture group 1 becomes `ABA`. A match is found beginning with the second `A`, at offset 3, after which the internal pointer is again moved forward one character, to a location immediately before the first `B`, and the process is repeated.

Suppose that the regular expression

```
(?=(.{3})).+\1
```

were used instead. After concluding that `ZAB` appears only once in the string, the pointer sits before the first `A` and capture group 1 contains `ABA`. `.+\1` then matches `ABABABCACACABAABA` (showing that `ABA` is repeated). However, the internal pointer is then moved to a location immediately before the first `D`, causing us to miss several 3-character strings that are repeated. Making `.+` non-greedy `((?=(.{3})).+?\1` helps but we still miss `BAB` and `ACA`.